# Count added controls in Dynamic Placeholder

Tags: dynamic-placeholder

I have a dynamig plceholder in a web control (not mvc - don't ask).  I'd like to identify the id assigned to that placeholder and the number of items added to it.

Any ideas how to do this that's not a tortuous loop of string functions?

Sitecore 9

Comment: You need to add some details. Are you in the context of that web control already and the page is a process of rendering? Do you want to count components placed directly in that placeholder only?

Comment: What implementation of Dynamic Placeholders are you using? Is it the Fortis one or another? AFAIK - none really supported WebForms without some effort.

Comment: @MarekMusielak I'm not certain.  But, I definitely can't get to RenderingContext

"Do you want to count components placed directly in that placeholder only?"
Yes.  I can get all the components on the page.  And, I can filter those down to the ones in my placeholder if I hard-code the id.  It's getting that dynamic id that is causing me the issue

Also, I suspect this is not the best way to go about it

Comment: @RichardSeal I believe it's the ootb Sitecore 9 implementation.  Yes, with quite a bit of extending to get them working (was like this when I got here)

Comment: Maybe - describe what you need this for. What is the reason you want to do this? The OOTB Dynamic placeholders do not support webforms, so its likely that you have something very custom to get that working, so it would be hard to offer a solution

Comment: @RichardSeal Our analytics team want an attribute added to a wrapping div.  For example on a carousel we would have the 'carousel' div with a placeholder that can have 'slides' added to it.  They want the carousel div to have an attribute 'no-of-slides' added

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler just to add that directly in the component code?